# Android Shell Syntax error: 'fi' unexpected

Tags: android, bash, shell

I try to run following Bash Code on my Android 5.1 Terminal (rooted, bussybox) but getting the error

```
Syntax error: 'fi' unexpected
```

The code:

```
if [ $api -lt 14 ]; then
    run=/data/data/com.googlecode.android_scripting/files/run_pie
    if ! [ -x $run ]; then
        echo "need root permission to launch run_pie/python"
        ls -l "$run"
        su -c "$run $bin/bin/python $*"
    else
        $run $bin/bin/python $*
    fi
else
    $bin/bin/python $*
fi
```

I'm not advanced using bash! I follow up some bash tutorials, searching for the error but I can't find the failure?!

Comment: Doesn't BusyBox include ash rather than bash? Anyway, the syntax for `if` statements should be the same. Have you tried including a shebang at the beginning of your script (e.g. `#!/bin/busybox sh`) ?

Comment: when I add a shebang like #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh and call the script with "python" (Name of the file located in system/bin) in Terminal I get "no such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever defined api ?

1. At the beginning of the file, you'd better use #!/bin/bash to define the shell to use.
2. api should be defined before you use it in '[ ]'， try this:

   if [ -n "$api" ] && [ $api -lt 14 ]; then

Comment: when I add a shebang like #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh and call the script with "python" (Name of the file located in system/bin) in Terminal I get "no such file or directory"

Comment: $api is definied at beginning of the script.